# node 18 react express app throwing "content decoding failed 200" when rendering gzip static content

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I am working on upgrading react express js application to node 18 and webpack 5, the application works just fine with webpack 4, however, when updating to webpack 5 and trying to run `yarn dev` i see the following error in the console and application css does not load as expected

`failed to load resource: net::Err_content_decoding_failed`

this error goes away when i unset the `etag header` from the code

app.use(express.static('public', {...config.cacheConfig, setHeaders}));

and just use

app.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip)
app.use(express.static('public' )) and set

however, the css/js does not work as intended, any solutions to make this work?

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { DefinePlugin, IgnorePlugin } = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const LoadablePlugin = require('@loadable/webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

function getEnvironmentConfig(envConfig, env) {
  return  {};
}

const copyPlugin = new CopyWebpackPlugin(
  { patterns: [{ from: './src/public/favicon.ico' }] },
  {
    copyUnmodified: true,
  },
);
const reactLoadablePlugin = new LoadablePlugin({
  filename: '../loadable.json',
});

const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');

const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.base');

/**
 * Gets the Webpack configuration for the React bundle.
 *
 * @param {{ ENV: string }} env
 *   The Webpack environment.
 */
const compressionPlugin = new CompressionPlugin({
  test: /\.(js|map|css|json|html)$/i,
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  // [path] is a path relative to output.path
  exclude: '../loadable-stats.json',
  minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
});

function reactConfig(env) {
  return merge(
    commonConfig(env),
    {
      target: 'web',
      devtool: 'source-map',
      entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client.js'),
        landingPage: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          'src/mycomponent.js',
        ),
        Wrapper: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/wrapper.js'),
        ),
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '',
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader',
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  url: false,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          process: 'process/browser',
        }),
        reactLoadablePlugin,
        new DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.WEBPACK_TARGET': JSON.stringify('web'),
          'process.env.FLAVOR': JSON.stringify(env.BUILD_ENV),
        }),
        new IgnorePlugin({
          resourceRegExp: /^\.\/cpme\/content/,
          contextRegExp: /@some-library\/component\/dist$/,
        }),
        compressionPlugin,
      ],
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          maxInitialRequests: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    getEnvironmentConfig(
      {
        prod: {
          plugins: [copyPlugin],
        },
        dev: {
          plugins: [
            copyPlugin,
            new DashboardPlugin(),
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
          ],
        },
      },
      env,
    ),
  );
}

module.exports = (env = { BUILD_ENV: 'dev' }) => {
  if (!env.BUILD_ENV || env.BUILD_ENV === '$FLAVOR') {
    env.BUILD_ENV = 'dev';
  }
  const config = [reactConfig(env)];
  if (env.WEBPACK_LOG_LEVEL === 'VERBOSE') {
    console.log(
      'Final config',
      JSON.stringify(
        config,
        (key, value) =>
          value instanceof RegExp ? `[RegExp(${value.toString()})]` : value,
        2,
      ),
    );
  }
  return config;
};
```

Comment: if you're not compressing output or not sure if it's compressed why You set `app.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip)`  which tells to browser that content is compressed? And of course etag will be different from compressed data's etag. also update Your question with code details. we don't know where what You defined.

Comment: The compression is done in webpack.client
const compressionPlugin = new CompressionPlugin({
  test: /\.(js|map|css|json|html)$/i,
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  // [path] is a path relative to output.path
  exclude: '../loadable-stats.json',
  minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
});

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to the `compression-webpack-plugin`, the code was setup to create *.gz files in the `puplic folder` however,  the web server was serving `*.js files, causing the issue.

The issue was resolved by changing the compressionplugin configuration(below)

```js
const compressionPlugin = new CompressionPlugin({
  test: /\.(js|css|json|html)$/i,
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  filename: './[path]',
  deleteOriginalAssets: true,
  // [path] is a path relative to output.path
  exclude: '../loadable-stats.json',
  minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
});
```